# On the definition of the bosonic one-particle reduced density matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, mathematical-physics, density-operator, identical-particles

Consider the bosonic/fermionic Fock space $F^\pm:=\bigoplus\limits_{N=0}^\infty H_N^{\pm}$, where $H^+_N:=\vee^N \mathfrak h$ and $H^-_N:=\wedge^N \mathfrak h$ for some (complex, separable) one-particle Hilbert space $\mathfrak h$ and $H^\pm_0 :=\mathbb C$.

Define

$$ \langle f,\gamma_\rho g\rangle_{\mathfrak h}:=\mathrm{Tr}_{F^\pm} \rho\, a^\dagger_{\pm}(g)a_\pm(f)\tag{1}\quad , $$

for $f,g\in \mathfrak h$ and some density operator $\rho$ on $F^\pm$ with $\mathrm{Tr}_{F^\pm}\rho N <\infty$. Here, $a^\dagger_\pm$ and $a_\pm$ denote the usual creation and annihilation operators on $F^\pm$ and $N$ denotes the number operator.

**Question**: Under what conditions is the RHS of $(1)$ well-defined for the bosonic case? And under what conditions can we prove the existence of a positive semi-definite, trace-class operator $\gamma_\rho$ on $\mathfrak h$ with trace $\mathrm Tr_{\mathfrak h} \gamma_\rho = \mathrm{Tr}_{F^\pm}\rho N$ fulfilling $(1)$? Are these conditions the same?

More concretely, I am worried since in the bosonic case, the creation and annihilation operators are unbounded and hence the trace on the RHS of $(1)$ might be ill-defined from the very beginning. Is the condition that $\mathrm{Tr}_{F^+} \rho N <\infty$ sufficient to ensure that $(1)$ is well-defined?

---

I think that for the fermionic case this can be done as follows: We note that $a^\dagger_-(g)$ and $a_-(f)$ are bounded operators on $F^-$ (defined on the whole space) and from the fact that $\rho$ is of trace-class we find that $\rho\, a^\dagger_-(g) a_-(f)$ is trace-class as well and thus the RHS of $(1)$ is a well-defined sesquilinear form for all $f,g\in \mathfrak h$. Further, it is bounded, [because](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class#Properties)

$$ |\mathrm Tr_{F^-} \rho \,a^\dagger_- (g)a_- (f)| \leq ||\rho|| \,||a_-^\dagger(g)||\, ||a_-(f) ||\,  = ||\rho|| \, ||g||_\mathfrak h \,|| f||_\mathfrak h\quad . \tag{2} $$

Now the existence of a bounded operator on $\mathfrak h$ denoted by $ \gamma_\rho$, fulfilling $(1)$ follows. Positive semi-definiteness and the trace normalization are more or less trivial, from which in turn it follows that it is of trace-class, too.

*However*, the bosonic creation and annihilation operators are *not* bounded, and as such the above cannot be applied.

Comment: It might help if you could phrase this is a slightly less formal language (especially since you are, probably, not interested in an overly formal answer) -- it smells like the N-representability problem, but it is not easy to tell (for me) the way it is phrased.

Comment: In brief: Can your question be rephrased as "When is a single-boson density matrix compatible with an N-boson state?"

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thanks for your comments. Actually I am interested in a more mathematical answer. The question is only loosely related to the $N$-representability problem: I ask under what conditions on $\rho$ etc. we can define the LHS in equation $(1)$. More concretely, it arose as I (with, as it seems, too much confidence) wrote in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/738912/has-the-n-representability-problem-for-bosons-been-solved) answer that the definition $(1)$ there can be generalized for mixed states, which would be definition $(1)$ in this question here.

Comment: I see -- so the question is "for which N-boson states can I define a single-boson density matrix"? Why would there be constraints?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Yes. You're right (although I mean states on the Fock space, not merely on the N-particle space), I guess there should be (if at all) only "technical" constraints. But as I tried to state in my answer, I cannot see how this is done. For the fermionic case I tried to derive the existence and all important properties (hopefully in a correct manner).

Comment: I'm still confused; if I have a bosonic wavefunction $\psi(x_1,\dots,x_N)$, what prevents me from integrating out all but one degree of freedom?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I agree, but my question here is why the RHS of equation $(1)$ is well-defined and given that (under some, perhaps trivial, conditions), how we can derive the existence of a positive semi-definite operator $\gamma_\rho$ on $\mathfrak h$.